# javascript doesnt continue even though it should - mysterious

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple script which goes through a textarea and transports !hash tags! and @person names@ into two separate inputs.

However, unless the first of two regex conditions is met (word starts with '!' and ends with '!' symbol), it does not work for the next condition.

For example code on line 42 console.log(persons_parsed); doesnt execute at all, unless !hash tag! typed into the textarea.

How to make it work, so I could only enter @person name@ and it would fill it in the input#persons_jquery ?

Code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yz2jw/1/

The problematic part

```
if (tags_parsed.length > 0) {

        var vysledek_tags = null;
        for (i = 0; i < tags_parsed.length; i++) {
            if (vysledek_tags) {
                var vysledek_tags = vysledek_tags + ', ' + tags_parsed[i].replace(/[!]/g, '');
            } else {
                var vysledek_tags = tags_parsed[i].replace(/[!]/g, '');
            }
        }
        $('#tags_jquery').val(vysledek_tags);

    }
    console.log(persons_parsed); // THIS DOESNT RETURN ANY VALUE!!!

    if (persons_parsed.length > 0) {

        var vysledek = null;
        for (i = 0; i < persons_parsed.length; i++) {
            if (vysledek) {
                var vysledek = vysledek + ', ' + persons_parsed[i].replace(/[@]/g, '');
            } else {
                var vysledek = persons_parsed[i].replace(/[@]/g, '');
            }
        }
        $('#persons_jquery').val(vysledek);
```

Thank you, 
Jakub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is substantial clean-up that can be done on this code.

The reason for your mysterious "works only when you add the second `!`" is that you were running your code only on keyup, and not when the page loaded.  Running it also on start would fix that.

You also add to the String prototype **on every keyup event**!  That's definitely a bad idea.  And for your simple case, there is probably no reason to add to String prototype at all, unless you're going to reuse this in a whole lot of places.

You also don't cache the jQuery selectors, running them again on every keyup event.  Finally, your handling of the output is much more complex than it needs to be.  You might want to look up [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

A fork of your fiddle which fixes these issues is at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/6sR9B/

This is the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var personPattern = /[@]+[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w| ]+[@]/g,
        tagPattern = /[\!]+[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w| ]+[\!]/g,
        $person = $('#persons_jquery'),
        $tag = $('#tags_jquery');
    var processForm = function () {
        var text = $('textarea.new-memory').val(),
            tags_parsed = text.match(tagPattern),
            persons_parsed = text.match(personPattern);
        $tag.val((tags_parsed || []).join(', ').replace(/[!]/g, ''));
        $person.val((persons_parsed || []).join(', ').replace(/[@]/g, ''));
    };
    $('textarea.new-memory').keyup(processForm);
    processForm();
});
```

Comment: Wow, the code has -40 lines. Thank you very much, not only for the code but also for the explanation. Personally, I am not a javascript programmer. I use google to program the small snippets I need for my project. Maybe I should invest some time to learn some basics of javascript.

Comment: Perhaps you should.  It can be an extremely rewarding language for a programmer.  And, unlike a few years ago, the language these days is even garnering some respect!

Answer (score 0):

Read the console output.  It tells you the problem:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Replace

```
if (tags_parsed.length > 0) {
```

with

```
if (tags_parsed && tags_parsed.length > 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But even without the condition the code was not working properly. Anyway, Scott Sauyet already answered my question which works like a charm.